# WPF InkCanvas Convert Text to StrokesCollection

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas

I've been working on my first WPF paint application for some time now. Having said that, I'm consolidating all the drawn objects into multiple Stroke Collections, so that each object could easily be edited using default InkCanvas draw modes ( InkCanvasEditingMode.Ink InkCanvas.EraseByPoint, InkCanvas.EraseByStroke ). Right now, I'm in need of assistance converting typed-texts (i.e. TextBox, TextBlock) into StrokeCollections. The application should allow text to be typed and erased just like Microsoft Paint version (6.2). Trying to avoid reinventing the wheel if at all possible.

I read a few articles with these suggestions:

1) Breaking the characters into individual elements and redrawing each as Stroke Collections

2) Cropping a region and convert that region into Bitmap and finally into Stroke Collections

Are there any alternatives besides these two suggestions? Any help would really be appreciated.

Best Regards,
Michael